# Why does Android Studio use the old source location when a project has been moved?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Kotlin-based Android Studio project located at C:\DEV\PROJECT1 which works fine. I copied the project SOURCE to C:\DEV\PROJECT2 and loaded it into Android Studio.

All of my classes as well as my namespace have a red underline under their names in the Project panel to the left and each editor tab. The IDE thinks there are duplicate classes because it's still referencing the source code in the OLD directory.

When I debug, the IDE says there are multiple versions of a class and at the top of the editor window you can choose from either directory.

This is causing a huge problem for me for multiple reasons, so I'd like to get the IDE to forget about the old directory when loading the new copy of the project.

I've tried all the tricks I found on the Internet but none of them work. I've manually deleted the "caches" directory in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google... I've done the same thing within the IDE with File->Invalidate Caches. I've manually deleted the .gradle and .idea directories, as well as all build directories.

I had a friend load the project SOURCE on his computer the same as I've done above, and he experiences the same issue. So I don't believe it's an environment issue.

Does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers mentioned worked for me. What I had to do was change the value of 'rootProject.name' in settings.gradle. Until I did this, it would always remember the old directory where the project used to be and would always use source from that directory.

This makes no sense to me so I'm going bo post another question to see if someone can explain why Android Studio NEVER forgets the location of a project name. I can't imagine anyone ever wanting that behavior.